# Javascript return count of same array occurence

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array set

array = [{name:name1,score:4},{name:name2,score:4},{name:name3,score:4}]

and, I want to get the count of occurence of this array with score 4,

result = 3

Thankstack

Comment: Could you give some details of what you have tried

Comment: Rather than posting a work-order, include a [mcve] of what you've tried and ask an actual question.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your array. Here is the code,

```js
 var array = [{
   name: "name1",
   score: 4
 }, {
   name: "name2",
   score: 4
 }, {
   name: "name3",
   score: 4
 }];

 function getCount(array) {
   var i, object, count = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 1) {
     object = array[i];
     if (object.score === 4) {
       count = count + 1;
     }
   }
   return count;
 }
 alert(getCount(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You May Try For This:

```
var array = [{name:name1,score:4},{name:name2,score:4},{name:name3,score:4}];
var count=0;
array.forEach(function(data){
   if(data.score==4){
   count++;
   }
});
console.log("Total count: "+count);
```